# How can I access such Directorys

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi I have installed an ANaconda3 AMI on an AWS EC2 instance and I want to install PySpark on it. The problem I have encountered is that I cannot access the .jupyter directory. You see in the following screenshot it is clear the directory exist for some reason I cannot access it with the cd command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXiZY.png)

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible the directory truly does not exist yet. Some tools except a default directory for storing configuration, but may not create the directory automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to create initial config files:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```